# More efficient way to call vector.size()

Tags: c++

Given a vector of ints I saw my professor writing:

```
for (int i=0;i<vect.size();++i)
{
}
```

I argue that his code isn't efficient and could be replaced by the following, am I right?

```
int vect_size=vect.size();
for (int i=0;i<vect_size;++i)
{
}
```

Comment: Compiler will probably optimize it anyway. But the 2nd one is better as `vect.size()` doesn't get called more than once.

Comment: @TonyTannous But I can't make such assumptions...

Comment: @BigSur why not? For most code this is fine. If you finish your code and profile it and find out that you're spending a lot of time hitting this loop, then yeah go through and attempt optimizations like this. But don't worry about it too much on a first pass. The most expensive part of software is the programmer's time - don't waste yours.

Comment: `vect.size()` returns `std::size_t` so your line should be `std::size_t vect_size = vect.size();`

Comment: Too many worries for something that would either be optimized away or a constant complexity call anyway.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis disagree. Extra operations degrade performance, though not at this level as OP is asking.

Comment: My guess would be that `std::vector::size()`, being a trivial inline function, compiles away the function call making it just as efficient to call it as store its value in a different variable to the one internal to the class.

Comment: I know this is going to sound daft. But in this case, I'd say if you have to ask the question, you should probably go with the first. If you know your target platform has a dodgy compiler, or you know your target platform would tangibly benefit from the second style then go with that. Otherwise your time will be better spent making sure code the compiler can't help with is optimal, and profiling while iterating on your code.

Comment: @tonytannous> no extra operations there. The compiler will do the right thing on all platforms I know of, provided you updated your compiler at least once in the last 15 years. You can check on godbolt.

Comment: I just checked and both functions produce identical code with `GCC v10.1 -O3` https://godbolt.org/z/uvjZYQ

Comment: If the loop body doesn't make external calls, optimizing compilers should give the same assembly for both versions. If there are external calls in the loop body, the size will have to be reloaded either from the stack (if you're storing it a local variable) or from the vector. If the size is stored in the vector trivially (as a member), the `vec.size()` variant saves a local variable and so should be slightly better.

Comment: It's usually implemented as some `(m_vecEnd-m_vecBegin) / sizeof(type)`, though, and then it's hard to tell. The division could be elided, the `m_vecBegin` load is likely a sunk cost and so it it comes down to whether an extra subtraction is greater than the cost of an extra local variable.

Comment: @spectras I was talking about `constant complexity call anyway.` by  Michael.

Comment: It depends what the body of the loop does.   If the size of the vector changes in the loop, the second form is not equivalent to the first.

Comment: Or do `for (auto element : vect)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0, vect_size = vect.size(); i < vect_size; ++i)
{
}
```

This way, you can limit the scope of `vect_size`.

Answer (score 7):

Don't fall into premature optimization traps like this. Your compiler is more than capable of optimize those lines if needed (and if instructed).

There are other things that you should note.

- Assuming that `vect` is a `vector`, `std::vector::size()` returns a `size_t` value, which is an unsigned type. Your compiler may warn you about the comparison `i < vect.size()` which involves variables of different signedness.
  If you really want `i` to be an `int` (there may be no reasons for it to be unsigned) you can use the following

  ```
  for ( int i = 0, v_size = vect.size(); i < v_size; ++i ) { /* ... */ }
  ```
- Do you really need `i` at all? Since C++11 you can write [range-based for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loops and, in general, you may want<sup>(1)</sup> to use one of the [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) provided by the Standard Library instead of a raw loop.

<sup>1) See e.g. [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2tWOdzgXHA) by Sean Parent.</sup>